# Does anybody know the origin of the idea of there being a population and a sample?

Tags: sample, population, history

I don't know if this kind of question is okay to ask on this website.

Comment: The answers very well might depend (quite a bit) on what you mean by "population" and "sample," because surely the idea of learning about a larger group from a subset of it is antique.

Comment: Aristotle (~330 BC): One swallow (bird) does not a summer make...  (refers to onset of summer indicated by the return from migration of these birds. )

Answer (score 1):

@NickCox from StackExchange put me onto this page maintained by [Jeff Miller](http://jeff560.tripod.com/) on, the ["Earliest Known Use of Some of the Words in Mathematics."](http://jeff560.tripod.com/p.html)

> Population and sample acquired a statistical colouring in the work of
>   Francis Galton and W. F. R. Weldon. In "Typical laws of heredity,"
>   Nature, 15, (1877), April 19th, p. 532 Galton wrote, "the population
>   ... will conform to the law of deviation [the normal distribution]."
>   Weldon applied statistical methods to "samples" of crabs in On Certain
>   Correlated Variations in Carcinus moenas, Proceedings of the Royal
>   Society, 54, (1893), 318-329.

As suggested by the comments of @whuber and @Kodiologist, the broader notion of learning about a population from a sample is an ancient concept that goes beyond the mathematical, technical use of these particular terms. Notions of learning by experiment are ancient, and perhaps some answer to your question can be found in the [history of the scientific method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_scientific_method).

Comment: The question is about the conceptual distinction between populations and samples, not the terms we use for these things. Are you sure that the concepts are no older than the current standard terms?

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_statistics
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founders_of_statistics

The birth of statistics is often dated to 1662, when John Graunt, along with William Petty, developed early human statistical and census methods that provided a framework for modern demography.